# Data purging in oracle

Tags: oracle

[ I have two tables TABLE5 & TABLE6

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE5 (NAME VARCHAR2(1), CKPY VARCHAR2(3), DT TIMESTAMP(3)); 

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘A’, ‘100’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘B’, ‘200’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘C', ‘300’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘D’, ‘400’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘E’, ‘600’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘F', ‘SKI’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘G’, ‘SKI’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘H’, ‘SKI’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘I’, ‘500’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-04 12:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));
```

---

```
 CREATE TABLE TABLE6 (CKPY VARCHAR2(3), STS VARCHAR2(2));

 INSERT INTO TABLE6 VALUES ('100','03');

 INSERT INTO TABLE6 VALUES ('200','04');

 INSERT INTO TABLE6 VALUES ('300','03');

 INSERT INTO TABLE6 VALUES ('400','04');

 INSERT INTO TABLE6 VALUES ('500','01')
```

I want to store the historical records in new table TABLE7(which has same table structure as TABLE5) and populate the records which are over 6 months old from now

We need to find out the records not having STS of '03' &'01' and join table5 and table6 with CKPY common values and store in historical table TABLE7 which are over 6 months old from now ...Whatever records are stored in TABLE7, should get deleted from TABLE5.I was able to move the historical records in TABLE7 but not able to delete those records from TABLE5...The query I have used is

```
  CREATE TABLE TABLE7(NAME VARCHAR2(1), CKPY VARCHAR2(3), DT TIMESTAMP(3)); 

 INSERT INTO TABLE7
  ( NAME, 
    CKPY, 
    DT 
  )
  SELECT T5.NAME,
         T5.CKPY,
         T5.DT
  FROM TABLE5 T5 JOIN TABLE6 T6 
  ON T5.CKPY = T6.CKPY
  WHERE T6.STS NOT IN ('03','01')
  AND T5.DT < ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -6);
```

I was able to move historical data into TABLE7 but not able to delete those historical records from TABLE5 after storing it in TABLE7][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f68hi.png)

Comment: "not able to delete" - why? If you get an error please show your delete statement and the error it gets. I'm guessing you've just changed `insert into table7` to `delete table5`, so you're trying to do a delete with a join, which Oracle doesn't allow?

Comment: Where do I need to include DELETE statement in query?

Comment: I have first inserted into historical table TABLE7 and then the records which are present in historical table TABLE7 need to be deleted from TABLE5...What is the DELETE statement I need to write

Comment: What do you mean? The insert and delete are two separate statements, you can't delete from one table as part of an insert into another. You haven't shown how you have attempted to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give your delete similar logic, joining table5 and table6 again, but you can't do that directly so you need a subquery; and as there would a small but non-zero gap between the two statements you'd probably want to `trunc()` the date you're comparing with in both the insert and delete, so something like:

```
DELETE TABLE5
WHERE (NAME, CKPY, DT) IN (
  SELECT T5.NAME,
         T5.CKPY,
         T5.DT
  FROM TABLE5 T5 JOIN TABLE6 T6 
  ON T5.CKPY = T6.CKPY
  WHERE T6.STS NOT IN ('03','01')
  AND T5.DT < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE), -6)
);
```

You might even want to use `TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM')` to keep the archived/purged data to whole months. Either way, use the same filter for the insert.

You could also, more simply, do:

```
DELETE TABLE5
WHERE (NAME, CKPY, DT) IN (
  SELECT NAME, CKPY, DT
  FROM TABLE7
);
```

but that might not scale once you've transferred a lot of data across.